# puppeteer cannot handle dialog

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

The codes is a copy of [this](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.9.0&show=api-class-dialog) with small change.

It simulates:

- Simply go to an add-on page in `Chrome store`.
- In the add-on page, click `Add to Chrome` button, and there'll be a popup. Click `cancel` button to close the popup.

but it doesn't work. The popup appeared, but didn't close.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

puppeteer.launch({headless: false}).then(async browser => {
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.goto('https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/evernote-web-clipper/pioclpoplcdbaefihamjohnefbikjilc?utm_source=inline-install-disabled')
  page.on('dialog', async dialog => {
    console.log(dialog.message())
    await dialog.dismiss()
    await browser.close()
  })
  await page.waitForSelector('div[aria-label="Add to Chrome"]')
  await page.click('div[aria-label="Add to Chrome"]')
  await page.waitFor(20000)
})
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

```
puppeteer: 1.9.0
node: v10.6.0
```

Comment: Is it a pop-up, a dialog or an on-site form that appears? If the browser doesn't open a new window or shows a message at the top, the dialog is part of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize event listeners before executing goto method